# Calling REST API with multipart/form-data

Tags: multipart, form-data

How to call a REST API from javascript with ajax or XMLHttpRequest to upload a file using 
Content-Type: multipart/form-data.

File content is in binary format, but the API which I am calling has following request format:
Authorization: Bearer <>
Content-Type: multipart/form-data

I am using following code segment to upload the file content:

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("POST", requestUrl);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");                                             
xmlHttp.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
            if (this.readyState === 4) {
                console.log(this.responseText);                    
            }                
        }); 
       xmlHttp.send(formData);
```

Where formData is the filecontent in binary format. Please suggest if this is the right way or should be handled differently.The file type I am using is an IFC file. And the error I am receiving is media-type not supported

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For uploading files to Autodesk Forge (A360), the following curl command works in a Unix-like terminal:

```
curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/$bucket_name/objects/$filename.ifc' \
 -X 'PUT' \
 -H 'Authorization: Bearer $token' \
 -H 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' \
 -T '$filename.ifc'
```

since IFC files are text (ASCII) files and not binary files.

Using the same Content-Type might do the trick in your case.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello, Thanks much for your response. Yes, for Autodesk, this command worked for me. However, I am using some other API's which is a POST request and expect the request body to be given in form-data. How should I address this issue. If i choose some different body data option it gives me  415 Unsupported Media Type error. Please suggest. Thanks!

Comment: Could you tell what REST API you are using? It might help to answer you.

Comment: Tried below but still gives me 415 error. var form = new FormData();        
form.append("", 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------abc123\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"aFile"; filename =\"another.ifc"\r\nContent - Type: text / plain\r\n\r\n');
form.append("", fileContent);form.append("", '\n\r\n------------ abc123--');var settings = {"method": "POST","url": requestUrl, "contentType": false,"processData": false,"mimeType": "text/plain","headers": {"Authorization": "Bearer " + token, "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
"cache-control": "no-cache"},"data": form}